# Is there a way to insert more than 150K records to SQL Server using npm Sequelize?

Tags: node.js, sql-server, sequelize.js, bulkinsert

I am splitting the records into array of 1000 and doing bulk insert to the table while looping. After around 60K records it starts to throw a `SequelizeConnectionAcquireTimeoutError`.

Is it something to do with pool size? I have it configured max to 60.

Answer (score 0):

Increasing pool size to 160 did the trick for me.

Comment: Does that not suggest a flaw in how your application handles (and apparently loses) connections?

Comment: I am trying retries when that happens still it fails. I guess it has to do with the previous bulk inserts holding on to the pool connection.

Comment: It could also be that you are executing too many query in parallel on the same table and you are slowly exhausting connections. You need to limit the concurrency in your code.

Comment: Yes it could be the case I am now going restrict the concurrency and see if it works.

Comment: Using a transaction will also make it "faster" since the rows won't be written until you commit.